# bash command 'echo -n -e "\x87" > /dev/ttyAMA0' not working from shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, raspbian

I'm trying to controll my [Roomba vacuum cleaner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foyev.jpg) by a RaspberryPi. But still having some problems.

I need to send a special command to the serial interface to start the vacuum cleaner. If I do this in the Bash it works fine:

```
echo -n -e "\x87" > /dev/ttyAMA0
```

If I put this in my shell script it does not work any more:

```
#! /bin/bash
echo -n -e "\x87" > /dev/ttyAMA0
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you made the script runnable? I.E. `chmod +x script.sh`. Also make sure you are running the script correctly `./script.sh`. For more help see this [website](http://linuxcommand.org/wss0010.php).

Comment: Thanks! It was runnable. But I run it not correctly. I tried `sh roomba_start.sh`. With `./roomba_start.sh` it worked.